# Как найти подсказку в firefox, элемент на котором сфокусирован сейчас курсор

Tags: windows, firefox, буферизация

Когда нахожусь в firefox, нажимаю на табуляцию, вылазать ссылки в виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как загнать значение того что сейчас находиться в буфер и как или где найти список всех возможных ссылкой через табуляцию. Как правильно это называется?

Comment: ПКМ - "Копировать ссылку"?

Comment: это понятно, но не подходит

Comment: Нет ТЗ - результат - хз.

Comment: ТЗ что это.....?

Comment: Техническое Задание. Ты нормально не рассказала чего хочешь добиться в итоге. Поэтому тебе никто ничего не посоветовал. Ну и мой очевидный вариант тебя тоже не устроил. Я конечно подозреваю что конкретно ты имела ввиду, но лучше дождусь нормально сформулированного вопроса от тебя.